# PowerShell Script that uses Test-Path for If/Else, If/Else not working when False

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Full disclosure, I'm fairly new to using Powershell and I'm working on a solution that tests if 38 excel reports are in a certain location and formatted with a specific date at the end of it (e.g. Excel-Advanzia-Outages 18 Sep 2015), copies them to another folder as backups, runs a macro in another excel workbook (that sorts the reports into subfolders based on the date), and lastly deletes the 38 reports from the original folder.

I changed/removed the date from one of the reports so that it would come back false to test what would happen, but it is still is trying to execute the code in the IF statement. Everything seems to work if all the reports are correctly formatted though.

I'd love to hear some feedback on how to fix the error or if there might be a better, more dynamic way to code this. Thanks!

Here is my code so far:

```
# Declares variable $a as today's date and will add 2 days in "dd MMM yyyy" formatting (Adding 2 days because this will be set up to run on Wednesday and checks for files that have Friday's date)
$a = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}" -f (get-date).AddDays(2)

# Verifies each Excel file is correctly formatted with upcoming Friday's date formatted as "dd MMM yyyy" at end of file. If true, code inside if statement is executed.
If ((test-path "C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Advanzia-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-AIB-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-American-Express-Corp-Srvcs-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Amex-Central-Europe-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Arcot-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-B+S-Card-Service $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Bank-of-America-Asia-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Bank-of-America-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Barclays-Commercial-Card-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-BOI-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-C-Card-S-p-A-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-CCUK Finance-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-CMC-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-COBE-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Degussa-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Deutsche-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Elavon-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Home-Retail-Group-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-IE-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-ING-CPS-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-JPMC-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-KBC-Bank-Ireland-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Lloyds-TSB-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Metro-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-NBS-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-PayPal-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Prime-Carrefour-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-PTSB-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Rabo-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-RBSG-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-RSA-Cyota-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Swisscard-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Telrock-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Tesco-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-TSYS-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Virgin-Money-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Wells-Fargo-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-WEX-Outages $a.xls") -eq $true)

{
# Deletes all files in "C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Current (Pre-Wrap)"
Remove-Item "C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Current (Pre-Wrap)\*.*" 

# Copies all Excel files from Outages folder into Current (Pre-Wrap) folder as backups
Copy-Item C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\*.xls "C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Current (Pre-Wrap)"

# Create new Excel Object
$objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application

# Open Workbook from specific location
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outage Protection Macro - Class.xls")

# Open workbook to first worksheet
$worksheet = $Objworkbook.worksheets.item(1)

# Run outageprotect macro
$objExcel.Run("outageprotect")

# Close workbook without saving
$objWorkbook.close($false)

# Exit Excel
$objExcel.quit()

# Remove all Excel files from Outages folder
Remove-Item "C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\*.xls"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because some values are returning true. What you should consider doing instead is store all the paths in a single array variable and then test and manipulate each path as needed one at a time via a foreach loop. So it would look more like this:

```
$Paths = "C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Advanzia-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-AIB-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-American-Express-Corp-Srvcs-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Amex-Central-Europe-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Arcot-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-B+S-Card-Service $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Bank-of-America-Asia-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Bank-of-America-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Barclays-Commercial-Card-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-BOI-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-C-Card-S-p-A-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-CCUK Finance-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-CMC-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-COBE-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Degussa-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Deutsche-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Elavon-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Home-Retail-Group-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-IE-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-ING-CPS-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-JPMC-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-KBC-Bank-Ireland-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Lloyds-TSB-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Metro-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-NBS-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-PayPal-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Prime-Carrefour-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-PTSB-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Rabo-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-RBSG-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-RSA-Cyota-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Swisscard-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Telrock-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Tesco-Bank-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-TSYS-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Virgin-Money-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-Wells-Fargo-Outages $a.xls","C:\Users\mathill\Desktop\Outages\Excel-WEX-Outages $a.xls") -eq $true)

Foreach ($Path in $Paths)
{
    #skips to next item in array if path not found (continue)
    If (! (Test-path $Path))
    {Continue}

    #rest of code goes here
}
```

Alternatively if a requirement here is that all 38 paths exist before continuing you could confirm that like this:

```
$Tests = test-path 'c:','c:\windows','c:\dontexist'
If ($Tests -contains $False)
{'path missing';return}
```